# Using jQuery flag appropriate li/day of the week

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a unordered list of store hours like so:

```
<ul class="days">
    <li><span>Mo.</span> <strong>11:00am - 12:00am</strong></li>
    <li><span>Tu.</span> <strong>11:00am - 12:00am</strong></li>
    <li><span>We.</span> <strong>11:00am - 12:00am</strong></li>
    <li><span>Th.</span> <strong>11:00am - 1:00am</strong></li>
    <li><span>Fr.</span> <strong>11:00am - 2:00am</strong></li>
    <li><span>Sa.</span> <strong>11:00am - 2:00am</strong></li>
    <li><span>Su.</span> <strong>11:00am - 12:00am</strong></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to add the classname 'currDay' to the li that corresponds to todays date. This seems like it should be super simple and working - but alas its not :) Here is the simple jq i'm using:

```
$(".days li:nth-child("+new Date().getDay()+")").addClass('currDay');
```

I don't get any errors, just nothing gets added to the dom.
Thanks!

Comment: `added to the dom?` ehat do yuo want to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/,

> Because jQuery's implementation of :nth- selectors is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting starts at 1.

Since the value of "Sunday" is 0, nothing is appearing. You need to add one, or use `eq`.
Try this:

```
$(".days li:eq("+new Date().getDay()+")").addClass('currDay');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3WVk5/

Or keeping your current order, compute `(new Date().getDay() + 6) % 7;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3WVk5/1/

Comment: Ack of course, I should have thought of that! Works like a charm, thanks soktinok!

Comment: I see my days are off in my list as well... Sunday is '0' so I need to reorder them as Sun-Sat.